# Entity Framework When to create custom DTO?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a pretty simple Repository Pattern in my applicaiton, but now I have an anomoly where I need to return the Code First Model AND some extra data.  See below.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersWithinLocation(DbGeography geography)
```

What I really want to include on the return model is the User instances AND the distance from the geography (in miles or whatever).

**Here are the options I see:**

**Option 1:** I could return the User object list, without the distance, recalculate a second time on the front-end, and avoid cluttering up my data model, but seems a bit redundant.. and, this may be impossible for certain situations and I just feel that this approach is wrong.

**Option 2:** Another option would be to create a new DTO that is either composed from or inherits User, say a UserDistance object. This would give me everything I need, but would I create a new repository for this?  I could see this as being somewhat unruly to maintain in large applications, if there are lots of variations of data that are returned with each model type.

**Option 3:** Implement some sort of dynamic ExtraData ViewBag layer of sorts, where I could arbitrarily pass in extra data along with a DTO.  This would create a tighter coupling between my layers, since the name would have to be known.  I don't really like this approach either.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would create a `Model` with the `User` and the distance, something like **Option 2** but without creating the repository, at least you need to store this info. If it is only for using it at a certain moment, you could do what I've just told. Hope my opinion helps you decide. Good luck!!!

Comment: Check out my answer below... I am essentially using the flexibility of 3, with the strong typed of 2, without needing to create extra objects.  Let me know if you like it (:

Comment: check out my answer below, I think that is what you want :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are to approaches to get rid of that double call to `Distance`:

```
public IDictionary<User, double?> GetUsersWithinByLocation(DbGeography geography)
{
    return this.Query.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<User, double?>(x, x.Address.Location.Distance(geography)))
                     .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

The other thing you can do, and I think is a little bit better is to change your return type, so you can do a simpler/faster LINQ query, here is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<User, double?>> GetUsersWithinByLocation(DbGeography geography)
{
    return this.Query.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<User, double?>(x, x.Address.Location.Distance(geography)))
                     .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

This approach you can use as it is with `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` or you can use `Tuple<T1, T2>`.

Notice that in both cases what I've done is to "store" first the calculation of `Distance` and then accessing it through the `Value` property of `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` in the `OrderBy` clause.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?  Any problems here?

```
public IDictionary<User, double?> GetUsersWithinByLocation(DbGeography geography)
{
    return this.Query.OrderBy(x=>x.Address.Location.Distance(geography))
          .ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Address.Location.Distance(geography));
}
```

The main problem is that we are running this Distance function twice, is there a way around this?

Comment: Hey Rod you can now check my new answer, let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I usually ask myself a different question: can I use the domain object for data transfer? Hardly ever the answer is yes. Why would it be? There are many cases where the UI slices through the domain model and wants a piece of this and a piece of that. There's (nearly) always a view model involved. And most of the time a view model is validated.

So for me: **option 2**. But the repository should not provide the view models. It should be a service layer that sits between the repositories and the view (the controller, if you're in mvc) and that orchestrates repository calls to collect data for the view models. The repositories expose `IQueryable`s internally, the services compose queries on these IQueryables and expose `IEnumerable`s.

Comment: I think I would agree with you except, my view models tend to have a lot of UI logic (UIHintAttribute) for example.  Moving ViewModels to the service layer, and thus the ServiceLayer interface would result in coupling the most of the UI behavior to the most abstract place in the application.  I think you are essentially suggesting a sort of DataViewModel that represents a logical slice of the Data Tables that can be composed in the service layer.  So then you have DTO -> DataViewModel -> ViewModel... Just gets too weighty.